# firebase storage check metadata in write mode error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

hi in my storage rules i have this code

```
match /Image/{user}/{image}/image.jpg {
      allow write: if request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid == user || request.auth.uid == 'nodeserver') && (resource.metadata['private'] == true || resource.metadata['private'] == false)
      allow read: if request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid == user || resource.metadata.private == false)
    }
```

if i try to write a custom metadata by client side like this

```
 var imageRef = storageRef.child('Image/' + uid + '/' + imageId + '/image.jpg');

            var metadata = {
                customMetadata: {
                    private: false 
                }
            };

            var imgref = imageRef.put(image, metadata);
```

i receive this error by firebase server

```
POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-4815133492804887736.app…Image%2F39IhnMU70uYrhJ9Y0XWBEMtQDR63%2F-KMP9NDx3D2gjJix3bpL%2Fimage.jpg 403 ()
service.js:303 x {code: "storage/unauthorized", message: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to…hJ9Y0XWBEMtQDR63/-KMP9NDx3D2gjJix3bpL/image.jpg'.", serverResponse: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 403,↵    "message": "Pe…n denied. Could not perform this operation"↵  }↵}", name: "FirebaseError"}code: "storage/unauthorized"message: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'Image/39IhnMU70uYrhJ9Y0XWBEMtQDR63/-KMP9NDx3D2gjJix3bpL/image.jpg'."name: "FirebaseError"serverResponse: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 403,↵    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"↵  }↵}"__proto__: Error__proto__: Object
```

if i remove this code from rules

```
(resource.metadata['private'] == true || resource.metadata['private'] == false)
```

all work well but i want verify the metadata. what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `request.resource` instead of `resource`. This is because `resource` refers to what currently exists (the file already stored), while `request.resource` refers to the resource on the request (the file being uploaded).

```
match /Image/{user}/{image}/image.jpg {
  allow write: if request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid == user || request.auth.uid == 'nodeserver') && (request.resource.metadata['private'] == true || request.resource.metadata['private'] == false)
  allow read: if request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid == user || resource.metadata.private == false)
}
```

Note that the `read` rule should use `resource` since it's referring to the file that already exists, while the `write` rule needs to refer to `request.resource` since that's what's being uploaded.

Comment: i try with request.resource and i receive same error

Answer (score 1):

Just update your storage rules to this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/barcodemanager-8dd41.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;//: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

In my case it solved my problem!